# Ошибка при использовании VUEX во Vue.js IE11

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, ie11

При загрузке страницы появляется такая ошибка:

[vuex] vuex requires a Promise polyfill in this browser.

Параметры:
Windows 7, IE11, Vue.js 2.5.16

В других браузерах и Windows 10 + IE11 работает.

Comment: Как вариант, проверьте не стоит ли в том браузере режима эмулирования IE10 и ниже.

Comment: Не стоит, но спасибо за вариант )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел причину, если кому-то поможет
Нужно подключить библиотеку `babel-polyfill` и прописать ее в `webpack.config.js`

```
entry: {
  app: [
    'babel-polyfill',
    './src/main.js'
  ]
},
```